# SSH into switch using paramiko module

Tags: python-2.7

I am able to open a ssh session into switch using paramiko. Able to enter the commands and gets it respective output.
My question is that I want to enter many command into the switch simultaneously. But before entering new command, wanted to know that previous command is successfully entered into the switch.For example

switch>enable
switch#
switch#config t
switch(config)
Enter the 2nd command, until i see # sign and 3rd command untill i see config.
Following is the code i am using

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('ip-address',username='username', password='password')
list =['enable','config t']
command = '\n'.join(list)
#for i in range(len(list)):
print command
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
print(stdout.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

use interactive invoke shell

```
##invoke interactive shell chan = ssh.invoke_shell(); chan.send(command + '\n') ;
while not chan.recv_ready(): print 'waiting for challenge' time.sleep(1) ;       
resp = chan.recv(1024)  ;  print resp
```